# Using dictionary for conditional assignment

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I use dictionary as a conditional statement to change the value of the variable?

for example:

```
a = 20

dicta = {10:3, 20:2, 30:1}

#compare using first pair as the value of a, such that:

if a=10: assign a=3
if a=20: assign a=2
if a=30: assign a=1
```

Thankyou!

Comment: so what your trying to do is to change the value of the variable using the dictionary?

Comment: essentially yea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can be sure that the value of a is actually a key in the dict:

```
a = dicta[a]
```

or to have an additional check:

```
if a in dicta:
    a = dicta[a]
else:
    print("error, value {} not in dictionary".format(a))
```

Comment: Or to get the equivalent of their ifs: `a = dicta.get(a, a)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a = 20

for k, v in dicta.items():
  if k == a:
    a = v
    break
```